# How to define a function based on its type?

Tags: function, haskell

I'm trying to define a simple Haskell function with the type `(m -> n -> l) -> (m -> n) -> m -> l`.
I thought that it needs be to defined as `f g h x = f g (h x)`, but apparently that's not true. How could I correct this function?

Comment: `f g h x = g x (h x)`

Comment: Could you explain why is it so?

Comment: reasoning how you can construct an item of type `l`, we definitely need the first function with type `m -> n -> l` to construct an item of type `l`, and it requires two parameters with types `m` and `n` respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the signature, the only sensical implementation is:

```
f :: (m -> n -> l) -> (m -> n) -> m -> l
f g h x = g x (h x)
```

This makes sense since we are given two functions `g :: m -> n -> l` and `h :: m -> n`, and a value `x :: m`. We should construct a value with type `l`. The only way to do this is to make use of the function `g`. For the parameter with type `m` we can work with `x`, for the second parameter we need a value of type `n`, we do not have such value, but we can construct one by applying `h` on `x`. Since `h x` has type `h x :: n`, we thus can use this as second parameter for `g`.

This function is already defined: it is a special case of [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (n -> l) -> f n -> f l`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) with `f ~ (->) m`.

[*Djinn*](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/djinn/) is a tool that reasons about types and thus is generating function definitions based on its signature. If one queries with `f :: (m -> n -> l) -> (m -> n) -> m -> l`, we get:

```
f :: (m -> n -> l) -> (m -> n) -> m -> l
f a b c = a c (b c)
```

which is the same function (except that it uses other variable names).

Answer (score 5):

```
f :: (m -> n -> l) -> (m -> n) -> m -> l
f    g                h           x  = _
```

Now you need to use the arguments in some way.

```
   g (_ :: m) (_ :: n) :: l
   h (_ :: m) :: n
   x :: m
```

Both `g` and `h` need a value of type `m` as their first argument. Well, luckily we have exactly one such value, so it's easy to see what to do.

```
   g x (_ :: n) :: l
   h x :: n
   x :: m
```

So now `g` still needs a value of type `n`. Again we're lucky, because applying `h` to `x` has produced such a value.

```
   g x (h x) :: l
   h x :: n
   x :: m
```

Ok, and there we now have something of type `l`, which is what we needed!

```
f g h x = g x (h x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f :: (m -> n -> l) -> (m -> n) -> m -> l
f    g                h           x  = l
  where
  l =
```

what can produce an `l` for us? only `g`:

```
      g
```

which takes two parameters, an `m` and an `n`,

```
         m n
```

but where can we get *those*? Well, `m` we've already got,

```
  m = x
```

and `n` we can get from `h`,

```
  n = h
```

which needs an `m`

```
         m
```

and where do we get an `m`? We've already got an `m`!